# Send data from Flutter Bluetooth app to Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, bluetooth, beacon

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k5MB.png

I am new to flutter and I'm working on social distancing app in flutter. I wanted to push the uuid of bluetooth devices discovered to the firestore can someone please help me in doing this

I can print out the discovered devices in my app and i can get rssi uuid txpower
but as rssi keeps varying and scanning happens continuously the devices get pushed into firestore multiple times
i wanted UUID to be pushed into the firestore only once.

Nearby.dart

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
import 'package:beacon_broadcast/beacon_broadcast.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'homescreen.dart';
import 'material.dart';

class BlueApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BlueAppState createState() => _BlueAppState();
}


BeaconBroadcast beaconBroadcast = BeaconBroadcast();

BeaconStatus _isTransmissionSupported;
bool _isAdvertising = false;
StreamSubscription<bool> _isAdvertisingSubscription;
final databaseReference=Firestore.instance;
String UUID = "3E4D7TJ9008";
void createRecord(String usid) async {
  await databaseReference.collection("users")
      .document("1")
      .setData({
    'uuid':usid
  });
  print('senddddddddingggggg');
  DocumentReference ref = await databaseReference.collection("users")
      .add({
    'uuid':usid
  });
  print(ref.documentID);
}
class _BlueAppState extends State<BlueApp> {

  static const UUID = '39ED98FF';
  static const MAJOR_ID = 1;
  static const MINOR_ID = 100;
  static const TRANSMISSION_POWER = -59;
  static const IDENTIFIER = 'com.example.myDeviceRegion';
  static const LAYOUT = BeaconBroadcast.ALTBEACON_LAYOUT;
  static const MANUFACTURER_ID = 0x0118;
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    FlutterBlue.instance.state.listen((state) {
      print("im in the init");
      print(state);
      if (state == BluetoothState.off) {
        print("bluetooth is off");

      } else if (state == BluetoothState.on) {
        print("bluethooth on");
        //print(device.id);
      }
      print("printing  eacon");
    });
    beaconBroadcast.checkTransmissionSupported().then((isTransmissionSupported) {
      setState(() {
        _isTransmissionSupported = isTransmissionSupported;
        print(_isTransmissionSupported);
      });
    });

    _isAdvertisingSubscription =
        beaconBroadcast.getAdvertisingStateChange().listen((isAdvertising) {
          setState(() {
            _isAdvertising = isAdvertising;
          });
        });
    beaconBroadcast
        .setUUID(UUID)
        .setMajorId(MAJOR_ID)
        .setMinorId(MINOR_ID)
        .setTransmissionPower(-59)
        .setIdentifier(IDENTIFIER)
        .setLayout(LAYOUT)
        .setManufacturerId(MANUFACTURER_ID)
        .start();
    if(_isAdvertising==true){
      print('Beacon started Advertising');
    }
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      color: Colors.lightBlue,
      home: StreamBuilder<BluetoothState>(
          stream: FlutterBlue.instance.state,
          initialData: BluetoothState.turningOn,
          builder: (c, snapshot) {
            final state = snapshot.data;
            print(state);
            if (state == BluetoothState.on) {
              print("BlueTooth is on");
              return FindDevicesScreen();
            }
            print("BlueTooth is off");
            return BluetoothOffScreen(state: state);
          }),
    );
  }
}

class BluetoothOffScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  const BluetoothOffScreen({Key key, this.state}) : super(key: key);

  final BluetoothState state;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _BlueAppState a=new _BlueAppState();
    createRecord(UUID);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.bluetooth_disabled,
              size: 200.0,
              color: Colors.white54,
            ),
            Text(
              'Bluetooth Adapter is ${state != null ? state.toString().substring(15) : 'not available'}.',
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .primaryTextTheme
                  .subhead
                  .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
            ),


          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FindDevicesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FindDevicesScreenState createState() => _FindDevicesScreenState();
}

class _FindDevicesScreenState extends State<FindDevicesScreen> {


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    FlutterBlue.instance.startScan();
    beaconBroadcast.checkTransmissionSupported().then((isTransmissionSupported) {
      setState(() {
        _isTransmissionSupported = isTransmissionSupported;
        print(_isTransmissionSupported);
      });
    });

    _isAdvertisingSubscription =
        beaconBroadcast.getAdvertisingStateChange().listen((isAdvertising) {
          setState(() {
            _isAdvertising = isAdvertising;
          });
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Find Devices'),
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () =>
            FlutterBlue.instance.startScan(),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[

              StreamBuilder<List<BluetoothDevice>>(
                stream: Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 4))
                    .asyncMap((_) => FlutterBlue.instance.connectedDevices),
                initialData: [],
                builder: (c, snapshot) => Column(
                  children: snapshot.data
                      .map((d) => ListTile(
                    title: Text(d.name),
                    subtitle: Text(d.id.toString()),
                    trailing: StreamBuilder<BluetoothDeviceState>(
                      stream: d.state,
                      initialData: BluetoothDeviceState.disconnected,
                      builder: (c, snapshot) {
                        print('entering if');
                        if (true) {
                             print('id----------------------------------------------did');
                        }
                        return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
                      },
                    ),
                  ))
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
              StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
                stream: FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults,
                initialData: [],
                builder: (c, snapshot) => Column(
                  children: snapshot.data
                      .map(
                        (r) => Card(
                      child: ScanResultTile(
                        result: r,
                        onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
                            .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {

                          return null;
                        })),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                      .toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

material.dart

````
import 'package:flutter_blue/flutter_blue.dart';
import 'nearby.dart';
class ScanResultTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScanResultTile({Key key, this.result, this.onTap}) : super(key: key);

  final ScanResult result;
  final VoidCallback onTap;

  Widget _buildTitle(BuildContext context) {
    if (result.device.name.length > 0) {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[

          Text(
            result.device.name,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ),
          Text(
            result.device.id.toString(),
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
          ),
//          _buildAdvRow(
//              context, 'Distance of the device',(result.rssi!=null && result.advertisementData.txPowerLevel!=null)?"${getDistance(result.rssi,result.advertisementData.txPowerLevel)}":"N/A" ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return Text(result.device.id.toString());
    }
  }

  Widget _buildAdvRow(BuildContext context, String title, String value) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 4.0),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(title, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption),
          SizedBox(
            width: 12.0,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              value,
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .caption
                  .apply(color: Colors.black),
              softWrap: true,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  String getNiceHexArray(List<int> bytes) {
    return '[${bytes.map((i) => i.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')).join(', ')}]'
        .toUpperCase();
  }


  int getDistance(int rssi, int txPower) {
    print("rssi");
    print(rssi);
    return 10 ^ ((txPower - rssi) / (10 * 2)).round();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("rssi");
    print(result.rssi);
    print("Transmit power");
    print(result.advertisementData.txPowerLevel);
   // print(result.device.name);
    print(result);
//    if((getDistance(result.rssi,result.advertisementData.txPowerLevel))<=2)
//    {
//      createRecord(result.advertisementData.serviceUuids.iterator.moveNext().toString());
//    }
    return ExpansionTile(
      title: _buildTitle(context),
      leading: Column(
        children: <Widget>[

          Text("Tap for more...",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0,color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),)
        ],
      ),

      children: <Widget>[
        _buildAdvRow(
            context, 'Distance of the device',(result.rssi!=null && result.advertisementData.txPowerLevel!=null)?"${getDistance(result.rssi,result.advertisementData.txPowerLevel)}":"N/A" ),
        _buildAdvRow(context, 'Tx Power Level',
            '${result.advertisementData.txPowerLevel ?? 'N/A'}'),

        _buildAdvRow(
            context,
            'Service UUIDs',
            (result.advertisementData.serviceUuids.isNotEmpty)? result.advertisementData.serviceUuids.join(', ').toUpperCase(): 'N/A'),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ServiceTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final BluetoothService service;
  final List<CharacteristicTile> characteristicTiles;

  const ServiceTile({Key key, this.service, this.characteristicTiles})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (characteristicTiles.length > 0) {
      return ExpansionTile(
        title: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Service'),
            Text('0x${service.uuid.toString().toUpperCase().substring(4, 8)}',
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .body1
                    .copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.color))
          ],
        ),
        children: characteristicTiles,
      );
    } else {
      return ListTile(
        title: Text('Service'),
        subtitle:
        Text('0x${service.uuid.toString().toUpperCase().substring(4, 8)}'),
      );
    }
  }
}

class CharacteristicTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final BluetoothCharacteristic characteristic;
  final List<DescriptorTile> descriptorTiles;
  final VoidCallback onReadPressed;
  final VoidCallback onWritePressed;
  final VoidCallback onNotificationPressed;

  const CharacteristicTile(
      {Key key,
        this.characteristic,
        this.descriptorTiles,
        this.onReadPressed,
        this.onWritePressed,
        this.onNotificationPressed})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
      stream: characteristic.value,
      initialData: characteristic.lastValue,
      builder: (c, snapshot) {
        final value = snapshot.data;
        return ExpansionTile(
          title: ListTile(
            title: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Characteristic'),
                Text(
                    '0x${characteristic.uuid.toString().toUpperCase().substring(4, 8)}',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.copyWith(
                        color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.color))
              ],
            ),
            subtitle: Text(value.toString()),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          ),
          children: descriptorTiles,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class DescriptorTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final BluetoothDescriptor descriptor;
  final VoidCallback onReadPressed;
  final VoidCallback onWritePressed;

  const DescriptorTile(
      {Key key, this.descriptor, this.onReadPressed, this.onWritePressed})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Descriptor'),
          Text('0x${descriptor.uuid.toString().toUpperCase().substring(4, 8)}',
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .body1
                  .copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.color))
        ],
      ),
      subtitle: StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
        stream: descriptor.value,
        initialData: descriptor.lastValue,
        builder: (c, snapshot) => Text(snapshot.data.toString()),
      ),
      trailing: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.file_download,
              color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color.withOpacity(0.5),
            ),
            onPressed: onReadPressed,
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.file_upload,
              color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color.withOpacity(0.5),
            ),
            onPressed: onWritePressed,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AdapterStateTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const AdapterStateTile({Key key, @required this.state}) : super(key: key);

  final BluetoothState state;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.redAccent,
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(
          'Bluetooth adapter is ${state.toString().substring(15)}',
          style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.subhead,
        ),
        trailing: Icon(
          Icons.error,
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.subhead.color,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: If your using the RSSI to determine distance you need to know while its linked to the distance it is not the only factor aka objects in the way reflections etc. But, what I recommend for your implementation is have a simple system that only adds a device if it is not already listed as opposed to creating it over and over again. If you want the new data just update the RSSI. Note with BLE scans you can filter by RSSI so you can just state it needs to be above (X) if it is see if that device is added to the database if not add it.

Comment: could you share the data structure you are using in datastore?  a way to achieve adding only if not exist can be to have the UUID as the key of the documents in firestore

Comment: @ThomasMorris can u please help me  with the code to check whether the device is already added in firestore or not.

Comment: @JoséSoní i didnt get what u meant by share the data structure .And hoe to use UUID as key of documents in firestore

Comment: By the data structure I refer to how the documents and collections are organized in Firestore.  What I mentioned is that each document has an ID and this one needs to be unique so by having the UUID as ID it will be enforced to be unique so they will only be added once each

Comment: @JoséSoní I have added the image link at the top  of firestore database.In the app its showing just 2 devices nearby But since one of the device's rssi keeps  changing it is added many times(as u can see in the documents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid adding it additional times there are two altenatives.

**Alternative 1:**

- Index the uuid field, as this will allow you to query over this field
- Before writing query for documents with this uuid
- Write only if the response is empty

This alternative has the advantage that no changes need to be done on firestore and minimun changes on the code, however will have the disadvantage that each write attempt will be preceeded by a read and reads are billed.

**Alternative 2:**

Change the data structucture on Firestore so that the UUID is the document ID

This has the advantage that the writes won't be preceeded by a read therefore its cheaper on firestore costs.  However it needs more code edition and will need to change the data stucture.

for the code the main change is on the following method:

```
void createRecord(String usid) async {
  await databaseReference.collection("users")
      .document(usid)
      .setData({
    'uuid':usid
  });
  print('senddddddddingggggg');
  DocumentReference ref = await databaseReference.collection("users")
      .document(usid)
      .setData({
    'uuid':usid
  });
  print(ref.documentID);
}
```